# Is there a way to render JAVA components/containers in a HTML/XML fashion?

Tags: java, html, xml, components, containers

I'm not aware of tools that are being developed for java, but i think it would be a good idea to create an engine that would interpret xml/html-like strings and render them into a tree of container and component objects. Example:

```
<JFrame title="This is a GUI stand-alone App">
    <JPanel bgColor="blue">
        <JPanel align="center">Some Text</JPanel>
        <JButton align="bottom" value="click" />
    </JPanel>
</JFrame>
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
...
```

ah, I'm not going to write thousand lines of code here, you know what mean!!!

Comment: "ah, I'm not going to write thousand lines of code here, you know what mean!!!" - wrong!  It's not at all clear what you're after and a few more words might help.

Comment: @Don Roby: I'm sorry, I'm new to Java and didn't like the idea of having to create many objects in order to create a simple container to contain just some components in it. You would have to create an object of type container, then create another container, add to the previous, then create a component (say a JButton) and add, and then set the attributes mannually, all this is very painful, so i was wondering if there was a more simplified way to go about, by providing a string to a method that parses it and returns the objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching "XML To String" in Google, you can see there are frameworks dedicated to that :

- [SwixML](http://www.swixml.org/)
- [SwingML](http://swingml.sourceforge.net/)

I personnaly never used them, but you could give it a try.

Comment: thanks for the search! i might not even use those myself, but i think it would be worth taking a look at the source codes to learn something new...